# Foreign key has nil value when using create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a new Player and the match_id is filled with a call to a class method:
When I run this code, the match_id gets a nil value assigned, while the Game is there and it returns a proper Game object. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Player.create(game_id: Game.default_game)
```

The "default_game" class method looks like this:

```
  def self.default_game
    Game.where(name: "Poker").first
  end
```

Comment: When you said `match_id` in the first sentence, did you mean `game_id`?

Comment: You said Game is proper object, but what about Game.default_game?

Comment: Sorry, yes I mean match_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ActiveRecord model associations are setup correctly, you can do:

```
Player.create(game: Game.default_game)
```

Alternatively, you can set the id more directly:

```
Player.create(game_id: Game.default_game.id)
```

Comment: When I use the first option, it returns "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: game". With the second option it returns "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id".

Comment: Then your Player model needs: `attr_accessible :game` For the second part that suggests there is another problem and that default_game is not returning a game, or at least one without an id (possible not persisted to the database).

Comment: Your solution was right, I has some mingled up data in the database

Answer (score 0):

is the datatype of game_id have the same datatype of default_game?  In some langauges, instead of crashing, NIL Is a returned value.